# R unlist a list to integers

Tags: r

[revised version]

I have a large character vector in R of size 57241 that contains gene symbols e.g

gene <- c("AL627309.1","SMIM1","DFFB") # assume this of size 57241

I have another table in which one column table$genes has some combinations of genes in each row e.g

```
head(table$genes)
[1] ,OR4F5,AL627309.1,OR4F29,OR4F16,AL669831.1,
[2] ,TP73,CCDC27,SMIM1,LRRC47,CEP104,DFFB
..
```

this table has about 1400 rows. For each gene I wanted to find the index of row in table in which it is located.

To do that I used

```
ind <- sapply(gene, grep, table$genes, fixed=TRUE,USE.NAMES=FALSE))
```

The variable "ind" returned is a large list of size 57241 which looks like this

```
head(ind)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[1] 1

[[5]]
[1] 1

[[6]]
[1] 1
```

I know for a fact each gene exists only once in that table. So the numbers that I am interested in is the list one in each line above i.e. 1. How can I convert this into an integer vector? When I unlist() this somehow I get a vector of length ~500000 whereas I should be getting the same length as of the list. I have tried many functions and combinations but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure all those list items have only a single number? What does  `table(sapply(mylist, length))` return? Because `unlist()` should work just fine here.

Comment: Are they all in the same position?  You could use `sapply(list, "[", position)` to pull them out into their own vector.

Comment: Yes, one number. The code you mentioned returns: >  0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8    10    12    13    19    22    23    26    41    72   279   389 
  722 53733   866    83    68    45    45    73     8    24    12    39    46    22    28    27    48    82   465   805 and they all add to length of the list

Comment: You can remove the guesswork by providing a reproducible example. At the very least, `dput(head(your_list))`.

Comment: @Jason this means some of the elements in your list have as many as 389 elements

Comment: @joran Thanks, here it is: list(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)

Comment: @RichardScriven It doesn't. However your previous comment did the trick. Thanks, although I don't know how to accept that as an answer.

Comment: Your results from MrFlick's suggestion has already proved that you are wrong about each element of the list being of length one.

Comment: @joran is right.  I'm not going to post an answer until we can definitively know what the issue is and how it can be solved.

Comment: Thanks all. Revised my question with some background, hope that helps.

Comment: Seems to me the fact that your `sapply` returned a list indicates it's probably not truly 1 each.  When I ran your test example above it returned a vector.

Comment: I would guess the problem is your genes can qualify for more than one row in table$genes.  Add a third row with one or more of the `gene` values in it and you get multiple values in the list elements.

Comment: What happens in the ZNF23 row when you try and match for ZNF2?

Comment: You are struggling because you are clinging to what you "know" is true, namely that each gene occurs only once. This is causing you to "know" that each element in that list has exactly one element, but I can assure you it does not. Your results from unlist confirm it. So what you really should be asking is what went wrong with your matching that would cause multiple matches. I agree with the above comment that the most likely culprit is some genes being substrings of others.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to reproduce that behavior with either a list or a dataframe:

```
> gene <- c("AL627309.1","SMIM1","DFFB") 
> 
> table <- list(genes =c(",OR4F5,AL627309.1,OR4F29,OR4F16,AL669831.1,", 
                         ",TP73,CCDC27,SMIM1,LRRC47,CEP104,DFFB"))
> (ind <- sapply(gene, grep, table$genes, fixed=TRUE,USE.NAMES=FALSE))
[1] 1 2 2
```

I thought for a bit that you should be using `match` but after further consideration, it seemed as though there must be something different about your data structure. Try posting `dput(head (table$gene))` and `dput(gene)` to make your problem reproducible. You should also stop using the word "list" to refer to the items in that table$gene items. It confuses regular users of R who think you are talking about an R "list". You can try to see which of the items in your ind "list" has a vector of length greater than one with:

```
 which(sapply(ind, length) > 1)
```